# Phonegap - Why my div height returns 0?

Tags: html, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have some pages on my web where I put this on all my html code:

```
<div id="footer" data-role="footer" class="clearfix">
        <div id="footerMenu" class="ui-grid-d">
            <div class="ui-block-a footerBlock">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="images/global/bottom_menu/product_active.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b footerBlock">
                <a href="favorite.html"><img src="images/global/bottom_menu/fav.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-d footerBlock">
                <a href="about.html"><img src="images/global/bottom_menu/about.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-e footerBlock">
                <a href="settings.html"><img src="images/global/bottom_menu/settings.png" /></a>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#footerMenu {
    background-color:#23476E;
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    opacity:1 !important;
    display:block;
    z-index:1000;
}

#footerMenu img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:96%;
}

.footerBlock a{
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}
```

My JS:

```
$('#searchResultPage').live('pageshow', function(){
    console.log("height: " + $("#footer").height();
});
```

Then, my app will load `index.html` as the first page and I can get the footer height there by `$("#footer").height()` as described above. But when I try to get the height again from `about.html`, for example, the height returns 0.

Is there someone can give me any idea why the height returns 0?

Comment: you should show your css. I'm assuming the footerBlock's are floated?

Comment: using jquery mobile? I think it does some crazy DOM injecting and might have multiple ids or grabbing the wrong one. If I remember you have to reinit or init differently with jquery mobile. I believe `$(document).ready` isn't the way to go with jqmobile. Paste your javascript as well including how its initialized.

Comment: Read the http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0/docs/faq/ under PAGE. I bet your problem is based in one of those. You can't follow the same practices you use for normal websites with jQuery mobile there are a few hoops to jump through because of the way the DOM is injected on each page.

Comment: Hi kennypu I've updated my question. Hi Leeish, yes you're correct I'm using Jquery Mobile and I still didn't find how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely that the images are not yet loaded even though document-ready has fired (I ran into this recently). Since you have not provided image sizes, as far as the browser knows the div height *is* zero.

The simplest solution is to include image sizes in your `<img...>` tags.

Comment: Is there any other possible solution beside this?

Comment: Just specify the image size into the img tag.

Comment: Not unless you can figure out a way to get an event after all the images are loaded and then resize the div.  I've never been able to find anything that works for this.

Comment: Well, there is nothing that can work like you mentioned in comment. Finally I make the global variable that can be accessed from all page that contains my footer height info.